# Unable to install Tomcat 9 with service.bat

Tags: tomcat, windows-10, tomcat9

I have downloaded tomcat 64-bit windows zip. I try to install tomcat 9 with service.bat file in windows 10. But while executing service.bat from command line I see following error, eventhough I have tomcat9.exe in place and CATALINA_HOME correctly defined in env variable. I am not sure what is missing here. Your suggestions  greatly help.

Error while executing service.bat

```
Neither the Tomcat9.exe file nor the 'tomcat9'.exe file was found...
Either the CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly or
the incorrect service name has been used.
Both the CATALINA_HOME environment variable and the correct service name
are required to run this program.
```

```
CATALINA_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.54
```

Error image:

[image: Error while exectng service.bat]

Downloaded zip directory (tomcat9.exe available)
[image: tomcat9.exe available in directory]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CATALINA_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.54

The above value of CATALINA_HOME does not match your configuration: your files are not in "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.54" but are in "C:\Users\*username*\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.54".

Just unset CATALINA_HOME. The `service.bat` script is able to guess the value for that variable.

Comment: Thanks!! The cause of the issue is right, CATALINA_HOME is not same as actual tomcat zip file location. I set CATALINA_HOME as tomcat zip file location(I put zip file directly under c drive) and able to install tomcat.